# IBM hyperlegder Fabric Bluemix implementation - errror when deploying chaincode

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

While following the steps in 'Deploying your `chaincode` from IBM `Bluemix` `Blockchain` documentation, I'm getting the following error:

**Response Body**

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "error": {
    "code": -32001,
    "message": "Deployment failure",
    "data": "Error when deploying chaincode: Error getting chaincode package bytes: Error getting code 'go get' failed with error: \"exit status 2\"\n# github.com/VrushaliW1/BluemixApp1\n/opt/gopath/_usercode_/583850129/src/github.com/VrushaliW1/BluemixApp1/Asgn1.go:38: stub.GetFunctionAndParameters undefined (type shim.ChaincodeStubInterface has no field or method GetFunctionAndParameters)\n/opt/gopath/_usercode_/583850129/src/github.com/VrushaliW1/BluemixApp1/Asgn1.go:75: stub.GetFunctionAndParameters undefined (type shim.ChaincodeStubInterface has no field or method GetFunctionAndParameters)\n/opt/gopath/_usercode_/583850129/src/github.com/VrushaliW1/BluemixApp1/Asgn1.go:193: cannot use new(SimpleChaincode) (type *SimpleChaincode) as type shim.Chaincode in argument to shim.Start:\n\t*SimpleChaincode does not implement shim.Chaincode (wrong type for Init method)\n\t\thave Init(shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) ([]byte, error)\n\t\twant Init(shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, string, []string) ([]byte, error)\n"
  },
  "id": 0
}
```

Tried referring to the links :
[IBM Blockchain (Hyperledger) - "Error when deploying chaincode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41548003/ibm-blockchain-hyperledger-error-when-deploying-chaincode)

["Error getting chaincode package bytes" when deploying chaincode on hyperledger via REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171171/error-getting-chaincode-package-bytes-when-deploying-chaincode-on-hyperledger)

The go code build rightly but still I'm getting this failure error with 'Shim interface' issue. Is still anything wrong in the Go code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be related to the Go code in the Asgn1.go file.  The message is indicating that the signature of the Init function was `Init(shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) ([]byte, error)` rather than `Init(shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, string, []string) ([]byte, error)`.

For an example chaincode that works with Hyperledger Fabric version 0.6.1, refer to the “Learn Chaincode” example chaincode at https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode/blob/v2.0/finished/chaincode_finished.go.  Note that the signature of the Init function is `Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, function string, args []string) ([]byte, error)`.

Comment: Andrew Tharp, thank you very much for the link. Things did work out with that code. Now I'm are stuck up on the second step in 'QuerySpec'. I'll search a bit more on it.                                                                                                                           Also one thing I did not understand is , the Go code when I built it on cmd it did not give me any errors of 'Shim' so I was of the opinion everything is goo with the Go code . But the 'DeploySpec' from Bluemix worked only on the code being changed as you provided the link.